# How do I assign a JSONObject or JavaScriptObject to $wnd[x] in GWT?

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, jsni

I read some `var` from my HTML-Page using GWT Dictionary. The `var` looks like this:

```
var test = {
    "a" : "123",
    "b" : "jg34l",
    ...
}
```

Now I get via AJAX-Call new content for my JS var. At the moment I overwrite it like this:

```
public native void set(String key, String value) /*-{
    $wnd["test"][key] = value;
}-*/;

public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONParser.parseLenient(response.getText());

    for (String key : obj.keySet()) {
        JSONString val = (JSONString) obj.get(key);
        set(key, val.stringValue());
    }
}
```

As you can see I get a JSON-String. Parse it. Cast it to JSONObject. Take every key-value-pair and use the JSNI-method to set the pairs.

There must be an easier way to do this?! I want simply to say: $wnd["test"] = myJsonObject

Please help me, 'cause it is performance-critical step (up to 1000 key-value-pairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [JSO](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay) (should be also much faster than `JSONObject`)
Something like this:

```
public native void set(JavaScriptObject data) /*-{
   $wnd['test'] = data;
}-*/;

public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    JavascriptObject data = JsonUtils.safeEval(response.getText()).case();
    set(data);
}
```

I haven't tried myself, so I can't say 100% if it would work.

**Update**:
Instead of a Dictionary you can directly return a `JavaScriptObject` that supports hash like access:

```
public class MyDictionary extends JavaScriptObject {

    public native String get(String name) /*-{
        return this[name];
    }-*/;
}

public native MyDictionary getData() /*-{
   return $wnd['test'];
}-*/
```

Comment: Yeah this works, thank you. But it has problems with GWT Dictionary :( Dictionary doesn't recognize, that there are new values. With my approach from above it works. I think I have to somehow "reload" the Dictionary.

Comment: what do you mean with "Dictionary doesn't recognize that there are new values"? Btw. you can use also JSO with Dictionaries.

Comment: Problem is: For example the following is in my HTML file: `var test = {...}`. Then I use `Dictionary dict = Dictionary.getDictionary("test")` to get the contents of `test`. Then try to replace the contents of `test` using `$wnd['test'] = jso;` with `JavaScriptObject jso`. NOW: `dict.get("key")` returns the old value, BUT: `alert($wnd['test']['key'])` returns the new value. If I replace the contents of `test` using my approach from my post above it all works as expected. See my post below for the solution (It's simple: Don't overwrite `$wnd['test']`, but instead create a new `var` and use it.)

Comment: You said: "Btw. you can use also JSO with Dictionaries.". Do you mean it's possible to to say something like `Dictionary dict = Dictionary.getDictionary(JavaScriptObject jso)`? Do you have an example?

Comment: I guess when you call ``Dictionary dict = Dictionary.getDictionary("test")`` it will create a copy and thus if you update the javascript value in the host page via the native final method, the ``dict`` instance still holds the old information. Instead of a Dictionary you can create a custom ``JavascriptObject`` that supports a Hash like access. (see my updated answer for details).

Comment: Sure I could, the GWT Dictionary source code does exactly the same (direct access via `JavaScriptObject`). But as you can see in my example below, the purpose of my code ist dynamic translation of the application. So it won't be bad to (kind of) cache the dictionaries for the different languages. I can save some send/receive-action and reduce server load. As said before: Every response from the server carries about 1000 key-value pairs ;) I think I'll stick with my solution 'cause it's has this caching-feature. If I didn't want to cache the data your code seems perfect (and suuuuper simple!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version for GWT Dictionary (true dynamic language switch):

```
public native void setTranslation(String locale, JavaScriptObject translationData) /*-{
    $wnd[locale] = translationData;
}-*/

@Inject
TranslationProvider translationProvider;

public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    String newLocale = "en";
    JavaScriptObject translationData = JsonUtils.unsafeEval(response);
    setTranslation(newLocale, translationData);
    translationProvider.setLocale(newLocale);
    LocaleChangeEvent.fire(eventBus);
}
```

Every Widget that displays translatable text registers to `LocaleChangeEvent` and implements `LocaleChangeEventHandler`:

```
public interface LocaleChangeEventHandler extends EventHandler {
    void onLocaleChange(LocaleChangeEvent event);
}
```

In the `onLocaleChange` method it simply calls the `get(...)` method from the `TranslationProvider` class to receive its String:

```
public class LocaleAwareLabel extends Label implements LocaleChangeEventHandler {
    TranslationProvider translationProvider;

    @Inject
    public LocaleAwareLabel(TranslationProvider translationProvider, EventBus eventBus) {
        this.translationProvider = translationProvider;
        eventBus.addHandler(LocaleChangeEvent.TYPE, this);
        get();
    }

    public void get() {
        this.setText(translationProvider.get("myDictionaryKey"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocaleChange(LocaleChangeEvent event) {
        get();
    }
}
```

And here the `TranslationProvider` class:

```
@Singleton
public class TranslationProvider {
    Dictionary dictionary;

    public void setActiveLocale(String locale) {
        dictionary = Dictionary.getDictionary(locale);
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        dictionary.get(key);
    }
}
```

That's it!